# Pass values in array to a range of cells on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm tryin to read in a column of cells its numbers and backgrounng colors ,and copy it to another columuns.

I can read both and put values in arrays, so what I need is pass the values in these arrays to the range that should receive it.

That's what I'm trying, reading values in column A and pass it to column C:

```
var origin =["A1:A5"]
var destiny=["C1:C5"]

var ColCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(origin).getBackgrounds();
var ValCell=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(origin).getValues();

// now i have two arrays, ColCell and ValCell,
// that have backgound colors and Values of original
// cells in the range "A1:A5".
```

I can't figure how to pass values in `ColCell` and `ValCell` to ["C1:C5"]. Have anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to copy the values (background colors and cell values) of "A1:A5" of the active sheet to the range of "C1:C5" of the active sheet using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

```
var origin = ["A1:A5"];
var destiny = ["C1:C5"];

// Retrieve values.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(origin);
var ColCell = range.getBackgrounds();
var ValCell = range.getValues();

// Set values.
sheet.getRange(destiny).setBackgrounds(ColCell).setValues(ValCell);
```

#### References:

- [setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: that was exactly my question and your answers was the solution. Just to register here for any new users of the Google scripts, that may have same issue, I had tried  using `.setValue()`, without the "s" of the correct choice that is `.setValues()`, so I was getting the first values of `ColCell` and `ValCell` replied to all cells at `destiny`. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: @Leandro Guedes Thank you for replying and additional information. I'm glad your issue was resolved.